# Extract Video Meta Data from First Few MB on S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have a large collection of video files on S3.  I also have application servers running in AWS running a Java webapp.  From those application servers, I would like to be able to extract metadata from each video file such as is provided by the Quicktime movie inspector:

```
Source: /home/me/foo.mov
Format: H.264, 1920x1080
FPS: 29.97
Data Size: 16.8 MB
Data Rate: 6.70 Mbit/s
```

Now, I can clearly get this information from ffmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -i /home/me/foo.mov

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/me/foo.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2014-06-30 22:40:08
  Duration: 00:00:20.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6698 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6696 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-06-30 22:39:09
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
```

I could easily parse out the equivalent fields to the Quicktime output!  But, this would require I have the file locally.  Is it possible to do this from the first few MB (or some other mechanism) of a file hosted on S3 without downloading the whole thing locally?  The goal here is to extract the same fields as the quicktime inspector from a file on S3.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this from the first few MB (or some other mechanism) of a file hosted on S3 without downloading the whole thing locally?

Yes, you get partial responses using HTTP Range headers.
See "Sample Request with a Range Header" on the [GetObject documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html).

> Any ideas?

If you want to use ffmpeg to parse the metadata, you can set it in the object on the upload as user defined metadata. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

Comment: The second approach you mentioned sounds useful.  I may have to check if we can feed the first few mb's of the file to ffmpeg to make the first approach doable.  Checking into that now.

Comment: Thank you, I used this logic + ffprobe in the ffmpeg library and works great.  Do you think you can help me out here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537884/how-to-get-first-n-bytes-of-file-from-s3-url ?  Much appreciated if yes!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a very intersting tutorial on Amazon:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/extracting-video-metadata-using-lambda-and-mediainfo/

It uses MediaInfo because it doesnot need to download all the file.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the link in your answer. Links are useless if the content moves or changes.