# How to get (first n bytes of) file from s3 url

Tags: object, amazon-s3, get

this is a basic question, not very advanced, but I am a bit stuck.

I am trying to get the first n bytes of a file hosted on s3.  I understand the basic building block to the issue.  I know how to get the bytes.  Here is an example from the AmazonS3

```
GET /example-object HTTP/1.1
Host: example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date: Fri, 28 Jan 2011 21:32:02 GMT
Range: bytes=0-9
Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:Yxg83MZaEgh3OZ3l0rLo5RTX11o=
Sample Response with Specified Range of the Object Bytes
```

Now I have an s3 url, like this:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/foo/1/2/3/4/file.jpg
```

How do I translate this, into the kind of request specified in the docs?  I know this is remedial, but I am stuck, this feels somewhat opaque, though that could just be me.

Please help me deconstruct the s3 url to the components of the GET request example.  Help is appreciated!

UPDATE: If I am to Use the `GetObjectRequest` api, what would I use for the bucket and key in the constructor?

UPDATE2: In other words is it as simple as

```
// modelled after http://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/
private String s3UrlToBucket(String s3Url)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/.*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s3Url);
    if(matcher.find())
    {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}

// modelled after http://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/1/2/3/4.jpg
private String s3UrlToKey(String s3Url)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https?://[^/]+/[^/]+/(.*)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s3Url);
    if(matcher.find())
    {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

UPDATE 3: Can you please explain to me what the key refers to???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the AWS SDK for Java, you would just set the range on the [GetObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html#withRange%28long,%20long%29). Here is a code example:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest("bucket-name", "foo/1/2/3/4/file.jpg");
request.withRange(0, numberOfBytesToGet);
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(request);
//s3Object.getObjectContent() has a stream to your object.
```

Comment: Exactly. Or, if you are on the command line, there is --range on s3api  get-object: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html

Comment: Ok, I had a forward slash in front of the key, one second, let me try it without.

Comment: I tried this, I logged the bucket key pair `LOGGER.info("bucketKeyPair: " + JsonUtils.objectToJson(bucketKeyPair));
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketKeyPair.get(0), bucketKeyPair.get(1));`  This printed `bucketKeyPair: ["foo","bar/1/2/3.jpg"]`.  This file exists as `http://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/bar/1/2/3.jpg` but I still get `Status Code: 404, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 40C255CEEC40D40B, AWS Error Code: NoSuchKey, AWS Error Message: The specified key does not exist., S3 Extended Request ID:`

Comment: I had a bad link, nevermind, thanks this is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are struggling to do this in Ruby (which we were for ages) the correct syntax is:

```
s3_resource.bucket(bucket).object(key).get(range: "bytes=0-3").body.read
```