# Very slow AWS presignedURL download. How to speed it up?

Tags: amazon-s3, download, aws-java-sdk, pre-signed-url

I am reading 20 - 30 different objects in varying size using the S3 IAM and a unique presignedURL for each file. The download of all files occur at once. Each phase occurs in sequence. Unfortunatly the S3Client is not thread safe so we cannot use async operations. Some files transfer rapidly while others lag. The total operation can take between 7 to > 15 seconds. I expected greater performance from S3 since AWS advertises that it has high throughput.

I see several posts that are unanswered about the download performance from S3. However the problem seems to have increased once we introduced link ambiguation using the IAM and presignedURL.

- FYI my internet connection is broadband. It is unlikely the cause of the performance issue.
- The tests are performed only a few hundred miles from S3 storage and eliminates distance as a factor of performance issues.
- There is no server between the client and the S3 for downloading objects and is not the cause of performance issues.
- One caveat. We tried using async forAllChunked using the Rice.edu habenero api. When we did not have any errors due to threading problems, the download performance was still very slow. This seemingly should eleminate the idea that download performance is slow due to it's serialization in the for loop. Albiet performance should be far better if we can download files simultainiously.

Code attatched.

```
public void cloudGetMedia(ArrayList<MediaSyncObj> mediaObjs, ArrayList<String> signedUrls) {

        long getTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Ensure media directory exists or create it
        String toDiskDir = DirectoryMgr.getMediaPath('M');
        File diskFile = new File(toDiskDir);
        FileOpsUtil.folderExists(diskFile);
        
        // Process signedURLs
        for(String signedurl : signedUrls) {
            LOGGER.debug("cloudGetMedia called. signedURL is null: {}", signedurl == null);            
                URI fileToBeDownloaded = null;
                try {
                    fileToBeDownloaded = new URI(signedurl);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // get the file name from the presignedURL                
                AmazonS3URI s3URI = new AmazonS3URI(fileToBeDownloaded);
                String localURL = toDiskDir + "/" + s3URI.getKey();
                File file = new File(localURL);

                AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withRegion(s3URI.getRegion())
                        .build();

                try{
                    URL url =  new URL(signedurl);
                    PresignedUrlDownloadRequest req = new PresignedUrlDownloadRequest(url);
                    client.download(req, file);
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
        }
        getTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - getTime);
        LOGGER.debug("Total get time in syncCloudMediaAction: {} milliseconds, numElement: {}",  getTime, signedUrls.size());
    }
```

Comment: Is your S3 bucket geographically close to your location/the location of the host executing the code?

Comment: Also, is your date encrypted? Does your data change often or you're downloading the same files multiple times?

Comment: @Andre.IDK The clients proximity is marginally a problem. In this case, testing is  within a few hundred miles. Each object that is requested is different from the other. I'll edit the post to clarify. Thanks

Comment: Maybe try download files individually or did you know about getting in ranges: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540895/495455 - you can also use CloudFront and an edge location that's got a closer proximity.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson: Thx for the suggestion about using ranges. Proximity isn't the source of the performance issue.

Comment: Let me know the result of the ranges and don't discount average telco providers and try another network to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, were focusing on software, not the connection. This is an upgrade to a secure link using ambiguated and temporary links. The previous version's performance was far better. Everything except the client api and the "signedUrl" is equal to the previous version.